# Get highest AVG speed with Lambda streams

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, java-stream

I have to write a method with the stream api.In the method I should get the maximum of an integer value in an Object called "Winner", The Integer value I mean is the average speed value, I have to get the highest/fastest one.The Class looks like this

```
package U13_Lambdas_Streams.Streams;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Winner {

private int year;
private String nationality;
private String name;
private String team;
private int lengthKm;
private Duration winningTime;
private int stageWins;
private int daysInYellow;

public static final List<Winner> tdfWinners = Arrays.asList(
        new Winner(2006, "Spain", "Óscar Pereiro", "Caisse d'Epargne–
Illes Balears", 3657, Duration.parse("PT89H40M27S"), 8),
        new Winner(2007, "Spain", "Alberto Contador", "Discovery 
Channel", 3570, Duration.parse("PT91H00M26S"), 4),
        new Winner(2008, "Spain", "Carlos Sastre", "Team CSC", 3559, 
Duration.parse("PT87H52M52S"), 5),
        new Winner(2009, "Spain", "Alberto Contador", "Astana", 3459, 
Duration.parse("PT85H48M35S"), 7),
        new Winner(2010, "Luxembourg", "Andy Schleck", "Team Saxo Bank", 
3642, Duration.parse("PT91H59M27S"), 12),
        new Winner(2011, "Australia", "Cadel Evans", "BMC Racing Team", 
3430, Duration.parse("PT86H12M22S"), 2),
        new Winner(2012, "Great Britain", "Bradley Wiggins", "Team Sky", 
3496, Duration.parse("PT87H34M47S"), 14),
        new Winner(2013, "Great Britain", "Chris Froome", "Team Sky", 
3404, Duration.parse("PT83H56M20S"), 14),
        new Winner(2014, "Italy", "Vincenzo Nibali", "Astana", 3661, 
Duration.parse("PT89H59M06S"), 19),
        new Winner(2015, "Great Britain", "Chris Froome", "Team Sky",
3360, Duration.parse("PT84H46M14S"), 16),
        new Winner(2016, "Great Britain", "Chris Froome", "Team Sky",
3529, Duration.parse("PT89H04M48S"), 14)
);


public Winner(int year, String nationality, String name, String team, int
lengthKm, Duration winningTime, int daysInYellow) {
    this.year = year;
    this.nationality = nationality;
    this.name = name;
    this.team = team;
    this.lengthKm = lengthKm;
    this.winningTime = winningTime;
    this.daysInYellow = daysInYellow;
}

public double getAveSpeed() {
    return (getLengthKm() / (getWinningTime().getSeconds() / 3600));
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String getNationality() {
    return nationality;
}

public void setNationality(String nationality) {
    this.nationality = nationality;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getTeam() {
    return team;
}

public void setTeam(String team) {
    this.team = team;
}

public int getLengthKm() {
    return lengthKm;
}

public void setLengthKm(int lengthKm) {
    this.lengthKm = lengthKm;
}

public Duration getWinningTime() {
    return winningTime;
}

public void setWinningTime(Duration winningTime) {
    this.winningTime = winningTime;
}

public int getStageWins() {
    return stageWins;
}

public void setStageWins(int stageWins) {
    this.stageWins = stageWins;
}

public int getDaysInYellow() {
    return daysInYellow;
}

public void setDaysInYellow(int daysInYellow) {
    this.daysInYellow = daysInYellow;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
}
```

I tried It with this, but I still get 3 names and I dont know why

```
private static Double getMaxAVGSpeed() {
    return Winner.tdfWinners
            .stream()
            .mapToDouble(Winner::getAveSpeed)
            .max()
            .orElse(Double.MAX_VALUE);
}

private static String winnerAVGSpeed() {
    return Winner.tdfWinners
            .stream()
            .filter(winner -> winner.getAveSpeed() == getMaxAVGSpeed())
            .map(Winner::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

I hope you guys can help.

Regards, Lukas

Comment: All three results have the same average speed, so you get 3 results.

Comment: this : `(getLengthKm() / (getWinningTime().getSeconds() / 3600));` will return a int (whole number) that is just cast to a double - you are getting 3 results the same based on that calculation. You need to cast before doing the arithmetic. You should do : `(double) getLengthKm() / (getWinningTime().getSeconds() / 3600.0d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: After reading Mark Keen's comment, it seems like the main fault is that the `getAveSpeed()` function does not cast the length to a double, so the result is rounded. I missed that when looking through the code. If the `Winner` class was provided as-is by the exercise, I would ask around to make sure that that is the intended behavior. However, the most likely case is that the methods of the class were written by OP, in which case casting the calculation would be a necessary change. Thanks, Mark.

I actually get 6 names when I run your code.

Your problem is that 6 Winners have the average speed of 40.0, which is the fastest/highest one of the set. So the result you're getting is correct. The main problem you have is figuring out the requirements of the exercise, to see if you have to print out just the maximum speed, the names of the Winners that have the maximum speed, or just one name that has the maximum speed.

One small caveat about your code, in the `winnerAVGSpeed()` function, you write

```
.filter(winner -> winner.getAveSpeed() == getMaxAVGSpeed())
```

on the stream you're manipulating. You're calling `getMaxAVGSpeed()` for every single element in the stream, which means that you're going through the stream and calculating the max speed once for every element of the list. The thing is, the max average speed will not change at any point, so you can calculate it once before you start manipulating the stream, store it in a variable, and then use the variable, to make your code more efficient.

If you only have to print out a single name that has the maximum velocity, you could also do this in a single stream operation, by using `reduce`, a stream function that allows you to compare and reduce a stream to a single element with a custom function. There's [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) on this, but you can also find many different tutorials on how to use `reduce` on streams. It's not necessary though, your way seems more clear and useful to me.